# Delphi 7 : how to split a string into a TStringList

Tags: delphi, delphi-7

It's Delphi ***seven*** and I need 
to split a string into lines.

Specifically, I have a DFM as a string (pulled from a MySql database) and I want to split it into lines in a TStringList.

It looks something like this ...

```
'Oject Form1: TScriptForm'#$D#$A'  Left = 0'#$D#$A'  Top = 0'#$D#$A'  Align = alClient'#$D#$A'  BorderStyle = bsNone'#$D#$A'  ClientHeight = 517'#$D#$A'  ClientWidth = 993'#$D#$A'  Color = clBtnFace'#$D#$A'  Font.Charset = DEFAULT_CHARSET'#$D#$A'  Font.Color = clWindowText'#$D#$A'  Font.Height = -11'#$D#$A'  Font.Name = 'MS Sans Serif''#$D#$A'  Font.Style = []'#$D#$A'  OldCreateOrder = False'#$D#$A'  SaveProps.Strings = ('#$D#$A'    'Visible=False')'#$D#$A'  PixelsPerInch = 96'#$D#$A'  TextHeight = 13'#$D#$A'
```

eh

---

Answer: this turned out to be pretty much a non-question for me. Delphi sees the `#$D#$A` as CR LF automatically, so that all I had to do was assign the string to the Text property of a TStringlist  (this also stripped the single quotes from around each `#$D#$A`). So, I only had to add a single line of code.

If the limiter had not been converted by Delphi then I think that @Roald van Doorn
 solution would have worked, so he gets awarded the answer.

Comment: There are some gotchas with this technique.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's easy to convert a string to a stringlist, all you need to do is the following steps.

- Strip the leading `'`
- Replace all `'#$D#$A'` with #13#10 (thereby splitting the string in to lines again.
- Remove the trailing `'#$D#$A`

Assign the resulting string to the `StringList.Text` property, each line in the stringlist is now a line of the DFM file.

Comment: Also, '' (two single quotes) should be replaced by ' (one single quote).

Answer (score 2):

Let's try this code:

http://www.delphi3000.com/articles/article_4028.asp

Another thing: i see that you are using **TScriptForm** object. It is good thing that you give to this object serialization/deserialization features.

for example, read this metacode:

```
tscriptform: Myform;
the_stream: TStream;

myform := TScriptForm.create;
the_stream.create(....);
myform.unserialize(the_stream);
```

In practice: make a **TStream** descendant that manages serialization of your form, and uses it to encapsulate saving/loading logics of your form objects.

Comment: The link is non functional!